# Django Python Page not found (404)

Tags: python, html, django, href, django-urls

I just started my journey with Django and I can't figure out what I did wrong. Sorry for that simple question.

inz/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'', include('planner.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),]
```

planner/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.main_page),
url(r'^/student/$', views.student, name='student'),]
```

And my href in base.html:

```
 <a href="/student/">Student</a>
```

And my error:

> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/
>   Using the URLconf defined in inz.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ^$
>   ^/student/$ [name='student']
>   ^admin/
>   The current URL, student/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Remove the leading slash* from `^/student/$`:

```
url(r'^student/$', views.student, name='student'),
```

FYI, in the URL dispatcher docs there is a [related example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example):

> There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. For example, it’s `^articles`, not `^/articles`.

Comment: That is right. No need to add leading slash after r'^